# SQL Query error insert into

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to do this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SA_PRJ".usp_verify_allocated_time(p_uid integer, p_project_id integer,   p_allocated_time numeric, p_achieved_time numeric, p_task_desc character varying, p_obs character  varying, p_date timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS void AS

$BODY$
declare alloc_id integer;

BEGIN
   if not "SA_ADM".usp_check_permission(p_uid, 'SA_PRJ', 'usp_add_timesheet_record') then
    raise exception 'User ID % nu are permisii pentru aceasta operatie!', p_uid;
   end if;
SELECT *,
   case when SUM(fld_allocated_time) / 24 < fld_allocated_days 
then 
   INSERT INTO "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet(fld_emp_id, fld_project_id,        fld_is_allocated,fld_allocated_time, fld_achieved_time,    fld_task_desc, fld_obs)
    VALUES (p_uid,p_project_id,coalesce(alloc_id,0), p_allocated_time, p_achieved_time,p_task_desc, p_obs);

else 'Not OK' 
end as Alocated
from
(
  SELECT p.fld_id, p.fld_allocated_days, t.fld_allocated_time
  FROM "SD_PRJ".tbl_project p
  INNER JOIN "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet t
  ON p.fld_id=t.fld_id
  where t.fld_project_id = p_project_id
)AS Alias
GROUP BY fld_id, fld_allocated_days, fld_allocated_time
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION "SA_PRJ".usp_usp_verify_allocated_time(integer, integer, numeric, numeric, character varying,   character varying, timestamp without time zone)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

I want to make a function to join two columns from tables `"SD_PRJ".tbl_project` and   `"SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet` and make the compare `SUM(fld_allocated_time) / 24 < fld_allocated_days`
from an input parameter `p_project_id (WHERE t.fld_project_id = p_project_id)` and make the insert if its ok or not.

The input column fld_project_id can have more than 1 appear in the table.

```
tbl_ = table name
fld_ = column / field name

"SD_PRJ" = my schema name
\ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
```

Error:

> LINE 12:    INSERT INTO "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet(fld_emp_id, fl...
>                  ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO" SQL state: 42601 Character: 550

Comment: Insert into its the error sorry for mistake :)

Comment: Your error is because you cannot insert inside a select statement.  Instead try putting your case value in a variable and determine if you should insert based on the variable value in an if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you're trying to write an `insert` inside a `select` statement.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet(fld_emp_id, fld_project_id,        fld_is_allocated,fld_allocated_time, fld_achieved_time,    fld_task_desc, fld_obs)
select p_uid,p_project_id,coalesce(alloc_id,0), p_allocated_time, p_achieved_time,p_task_desc, p_obs
from
(
  SELECT p.fld_id, p.fld_allocated_days, t.fld_allocated_time
  FROM "SD_PRJ".tbl_project p
  INNER JOIN "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet t
  ON p.fld_id=t.fld_id
  where t.fld_project_id = p_project_id
)AS Alias
GROUP BY fld_id, fld_allocated_days, fld_allocated_time
having SUM(fld_allocated_time) / 24 < fld_allocated_days
```

Not completely sure if everything there is right, but that's the general gist of it I think.